# From editor to excel

Tags: excel, editor

I generated a file with Rhino for a slow tool. I can open the file in editor, however I need to copy it to excel with the space character being the column separator:

```
C180.36 X10.199995 Z-0.151999 
C180.72 X10.19999 Z-0.152 
C181.08 X10.199985 Z-0.152 
C181.44 X10.19998 Z-0.152 
C181.8 X10.199975 Z-0.152 
C182.16 X10.19997 Z-0.152 
C182.52 X10.199965 Z-0.152
.
.
.
.
```

Should look in excel like this:

```
   A               B              C
1  C180.36   X10.199995 Z-0.151999
2  C180.72   X10.19999  Z-0.152
3  C181.08   X10.199985 Z-0.152 
4  C181.44   X10.19998  Z-0.152 
5  C181.8    X10.199975 Z-0.152
6  C182.16   X10.19997  Z-0.152 
7  C182.52   X10.199965 Z-0.152
```

Is there any formula for that?

Comment: try to use 'Text to column' available in the Excel Ribbon... Or you could try to open this file directly from excel. Next go according to wizard options...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about Rhino, but if you have a *.txt file like the one showed then you can import it to Excel like what you want.

In Excel go to File -> Open and select 'All Files(*.*)' in the file type and then select your input file.
You will be prompted to a wizard where you can select the data format, and number of raws. Click Next and select 'Tab', 'Space' for Delimiters then select Next and Finish. You will have your data in Column, Raw format.

Then you can simply copy and past on wherever you want in the same Excel sheet or in another sheet or another workbook.

I hope this will help.